# Python + OpenCV = How to crop circle?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, crop, geometry

The below is the code:

```
self.img = cv2.imread(image,)
circle = cv2.HoughCircles(self.img, 3,
                          dp=1.5, minDist=1000, minRadius=100, maxRadius=1000)
red = (0,0,255)
x = circle[0][0][0]
y = circle[0][0][1]
r = circle[0][0][2]
cv2.circle(self.img, (x, y), r, red, 2)



    x - X
    y - Y
    r - Radius
    For example: 521.25, 506.25, 318.919
```

From the code how to crop the circle from the given example ?

Comment: what version of OpenCV are you using?

Comment: OpenCV version: 3.0.0

Comment: If your image is a rectangular grid, then you crop it using a line like `cropped = image[30:120 , 240:335]` where the numbers are the NumPy array slices that define a rectangular region of the image, starting at (240, 30) and ending at (335, 120). If you want an answer specific to your question, please re-write it according to [ask].

Comment: This question would be more useful if you'd provide some pictures.

Answer (score 3):

Its simple .. you need to get x,y co-ordinates of top right of rectangle and find with and height. Circles can be only enclosed in squares.

```
# given x,y are circle center and r is radius
rectX = (x - r) 
rectY = (y - r)
crop_img = self.img[y:(y+2*r), x:(x+2*r)]
```

Comment: As far as I tested you must use rectX and rectY in the last formula , instead of x and y

Comment: As mentioned by @Maham, `rectX` and `rectY` should be used in the final Formula,else it does not work

Answer (score 2):

After circles=cv2.HoughCircles(img,...)

```
if len(circles) == 1:
    x, y, r = circles[0][0]
    print x, y, r
    mask = np.zeros((w0,h0),dtype=np.uint8)
    cv2.circle(mask,(x,y),r,(255,255,255),-1,8,0)
    #cv2.imwrite(argv[2],mask)
    out = img*mask
    white = 255-mask
    cv2.imwrite(argv[2],out+white)
```

Comment: where did you get w0 and h0?

Comment: w0 and h0 = width and height of the image (and mask), `w0 = img.shape[0]; h0 = img.shape[1];`